# How to update mysqldump.exe in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

My want to export my database but i have issue on exporting process issue is that
mysql.exe version 8.0.13, but the MySQL server to be dumped has version 5.7.22
because the version of musql dump not same as the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't replace the binary bundled with MySQL Workbench, but instead set the path to it in the preferences (I think the error message that comes up for the mismatch even says so):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to backup your database quickly then use phpmyadmin to get a dump of your existing database to .sql file.

On your browser go to http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

Update password (im using xampp and I didnt confirm it on Wampp or Lampp versions).
Go to your xampp control panel installed on your machine and look for Apache "Config" tab, click it and look for

```
phpmyadmin(config.inc.php)
```

click it and it opens config file. Look for

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

Type correct password for login  to mysql, then save the configuration file.

Refresh the web browser to http://localhost/phpmyadmin/. Follow quick steps on the image, that is

1. select a database to backup
2. click 'export'
3. click 'Go' button.

[image: # 3 steps to back up your mysql database]